# Setting up Mirroring in SQL Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

I know doing something like mirroring in SQL Server express edition is not possible, but can we do real-time db backup and restore and setup some automated task which acts like mirroring and keep them in sync.

Answer (score 13):

Express Edition doesn't include database mirroring, but you can do something similar with log shipping. Log shipping is a technique, not a feature - it's just a matter of frequently taking backups on your primary server, and then restoring them on the secondary.

The normal way of doing this requires SQL Server Agent to run the backup & restore jobs - but again, that's not something Express Edition includes. You'll need some kind of job scheduler.

[Kathrine Villyard has a post on doing this with PowerShell.](http://www.katherinevillyard.com/2015/09/23/log-shipping-sql-express-with-powershell/)

When it comes to failing over, the basic concepts are the same as [failing over Standard Edition's log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/fail-over-to-a-log-shipping-secondary-sql-server). They'll be manual steps on Express Edition - but they're also manual on the big brother, too, so don't feel bad.