# which High Availability and Disaster Recovery method would be suitable for my SQL Express server

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, disaster-recovery

What are the considerations that would determine which High Availability and Disaster Recovery method would be suitable for my MSSQL **express** server?
These are some of the considerations I found on the internet

```
RTO (Recovery Time Objective)
RPO (Recovery Point Objective)
Criticality of Database Systems
```

https://www.sqlshack.com/useful-considerations-for-sql-server-disaster-recovery/

https://downloads.brentozar.com/Worksheet%20-%20High%20Availability%20and%20Disaster%20Recovery%20Planning.pdf

Above solutions look complicated for a SMB.

What would be an ideal scalable HA & DR solution for a small scale business with Maximum
of approximately 10 databases and if each database is around 10GB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: log shipping
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191975/setting-up-mirroring-in-sql-express-edition

Comment: How much data is acceptable for loss in terms of time i.e. up to 5 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day, etc of data loss (RPO)? How long can the business tolerate being down until the database is back online (RTO)?

Answer (score 3):

Only you can specify the RTO and RPO that are required.  But a simple approach is to take offsite [backups to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15), and have a tested process to install SQL Server on a new server, and restore all the backups in case of a disaster.

Another simple approach is to run SQL Server on a VM and have the hypervisor handle HA and DR for SQL Server along with all your other VM workloads.